# Cannot Import Name 'BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor' from 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery'

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to import BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery

here is my code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from util.dags_hourly import create_dag_write_append #this is class that I created, no issues with other DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery import 
BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor

def __init__(self, dataset=None, table_name=None):
    self.dataset = dataset
    self.table_name = table_name

def check_table_exists(self):
    return BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor(
    task_id="check_table_exists_async",
    project_id='x-staging',
    dataset_id=self.dataset,
    table_id=self.table 
)

with create_dag_write_append('test') as dag:

    a = BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor(
        dataset_id='data_lake_staging',
        table_id='test_table'
    )
    task1 = a.check_table_exists()

    task1
```

However it returns DAG import error on Airflow:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/manatal/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test/test_dag.py", line 4, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery import BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor
ImportError: cannot import name 'BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor' from 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery' (/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/bigquery.py)BigQueryTableExistenceAsyncSensor
```

I read the documentation from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/bigquery/index.html), but I don't understand why the library is not read properly.

my final objective is to check whether the table exist on my dataset.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Iqbal, can you provide the sample code of the class `create_dag_write_append` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out with a workaround. Turns out I can use

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

class ExistsOperator(GCSToBigQuery, PostgresToGCS):

def __init__(self, filenames, table_name, task_id=None, task_id_pgcs=None, task_id_pgcs_init=None, task_id_gb=None):
    self.task_id = task_id or f"check_exists_{filenames}_from_gcs"
    self.task_id_pgcs = task_id_pgcs
    self.task_id_pgcs_init = task_id_pgcs_init
    self.task_id_gb = task_id_gb
    self.bucket = constants.GCS_BUCKET
    self.source_objects = filenames
    self.table_name = table_name

def is_exists_storage(self):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(self.bucket)
    filenames = bucket.get_blob(self.source_objects)
    try:
        filenames.exists(client)
        return self.task_id_gb
    except:
        return 'no_upsert_task'

def is_exists_table(self):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    try:
        table_name = client.get_table(self.table_name)
        if table_name:
            return self.task_id_pgcs
    except NotFound as error:       
        return self.task_id_pgcs_init
```

I create additional function to check existence of file in cloud storage bucket. hope this helps anyone in needs!